# If $\tau_1\subset \tau_2$ and $X^*$ is separable for $\tau_1$ then $X^*$ is separable for $\tau_2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, duality

Let $X$ be a Banach space the associated dual space is denoted by $X^*$. Take $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ two topologies  in $X^*$ compatible with the duality  $(X^*,X)$,  such that $\tau_1\subset \tau_2$.

We suppose that $X^*$ is separable for $\tau_1$. Can we say that $X^*$ is separable for $\tau_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. If $D$ is $\tau_1$ dense, then the linear span of $D$ is $\tau_2$ dense by the separation theorem, and the rational linear combinations of a set in any TVS is dense in the linear span of the set.

Comment: Why "by the separation theorem" we have the linear span of $D$ is $\tau_2$ dense?

Comment: @KarimKHAN since $\tau_2$ is compatible with the duality, if rational span  of $D$ was not dense there would be $x\in X\0$ such that $<x,d>=0$.